# Get values in a struct stored in C++ set

Tags: c++, struct, stdset

I declare a struct called Position with 2 data members: x, y. I want to store instances of these structs into a std::set. How can I later retrieve the value of x, y from the right Position struct?

```
struct Position
{
    long m_x;
    long m_y;
    Position(long x, long y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
}

std::set<Position> m_visited;
```

What I'm trying to implement is a tracking system for an entity in a 2D map. Every time the entity moves, its current position will be recorded into the set, so that later I can find out where it has been to.

I record its current position by calling this every time it moves.

```
m_visited.insert(Position(CorX(),CorY());
```

And later, I'd like to see if the new cell which my entity is going to has been visited or not. If it is, then I'd tell the entity to pick other cells to do something by saying something like

```
for (set<Position>:iterator i = m_visited.begin(); i != m_visited.end(); i++)
{
    if ([X cor of next cell] != [X cor of a visited cell] && [Y cor of next cell] != [Y cor of a visited cell])
    {
         do something
    }
}
```

Problem is I don't know how to find the right cell which has the right data to compare to. Sorry if this sounds really confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterator `i` can be used like a pointer to `Position`, so you can write

```
Position visited = ...
for (set<Position>:iterator i = m_visited.begin(); i != m_visited.end(); i++) {
    if (i->m_x == visited.m_x && i->m_y == visited.m_y) {
        ... // Been there before
    }
}
```

However, this use of the `set` is not much different from a use of a `list`, because the serach is linear. You can find out if the item you have inserted is a new one without a loop by checking the return value of `insert`:

```
if (!m_visited.insert(Position(CorX(),CorY())).second) {
    // Position at { CorX(), CorY() } has been visited
}
```

`set::insert` returns a `pair` with the second member set to `true` if the item that you have inserted is a new one, and to `false` if another item with the same data is already in the set.

Comment: thanks heap for your answer. the first part was spot on. 
for the second part, I think you have missed a closed bracket just before the .second.
and I wonder if a new item would be added to the set if it returns true

Comment: @user2345939 I did miss the closing parenthesis, thanks! When `insert(...).second` is `true`, it's an indication that the item that you have passed to `insert` was a new item that wasn't there before the `insert`, but is there now.